# Proper way of saying "a The Sims NPC"

Tags: idiomatic-language

> This NPC from this other game behaves like a The Sims NPC.

Looks really odd. Is this the proper way of saying it or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This [X] behaves like a [Y].

The above sentence structure is usually very good for most noun-phrases [X] and [Y].

> This [NPC from "GameA"] behaves like a ["GameB" NPC].

In general, the above sentence also works for most titles of "GameA" or "GameB".

> This [NPC from GameA] behaves like [a "The Sims" NPC].

However, you are correct that this specific example is an exception that looks/sounds strange.

---

The most natural fix is:

> This [NPC from GameA] behaves like *an* [NPC from "The Sims"].

Re-arranging the second noun-phrase to be more like the first noun-phrase is the simplest fix.

---

There are also ways that "...behaves like "a 'The Sims' NPC" could be conveyed 'by speech' but I'm assuming a greater mastery of intonation would be required there.